# Is there a simple formula for the volume of an oblique triangular pyramid?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

I have the xyz coordinates for 4 points in space that are not co-planar.  These points form a triangular pyramid.  Taking any 3 points as the base, the 4'th point will practically never be over the center of the base, which (I believe) means that my pyramid is best described as being oblique.  It might even be that the 4'th point does not lie within the perimeter of the base triangle (when viewed from above).  The base triangle can be of any shape (no constraint on length of sides).

So I have these 4 points as XYZ coordinates, thus calculating the distances (if needed) is easy.  And I know the formula for the volume should be [area of base] x [1/3 height of pyramid].

I'm just wondering if there's a way to calculate this without figuring out the equation of the plane of the base, computing normal vector (etc) to get the distance from the 4'th point to the plane formed by the first 3 points.  Lots of intermediate steps involved going through all that - is there something that maybe takes the lengths (A, B, C, D, E, F) and with some multiplication, a few trig functions and a square-root or two gives me the volume?

Answer (score 1):

If you put one of the points at the origin, and you enter the coordinates of the three other points into a $3\times 3$ matrix, then the volume is a sixth of the absolute value of the determinant of that matrix.

The absolute value of the determinant is the volume of the parallelepiped with the given vectors as three of the edges. The base of your pyramid is half the base of the parallelepiped, and the height is the same, which works up to a sixth in total.

Answer (score 0):

The figure is a tetrahedron. You can get is volume easily using the formula

$$\mathrm{Volume}=\frac 16 |\det(\overrightarrow{AB},\overrightarrow{AC},\overrightarrow{AD})|,$$ where $A,B,C,D$ are the vectices. (See Volume in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron.)